# Property 'locations' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: json, windows, typescript, ionic-framework, geolocation

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class LocationsProvider {

  data: any;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

  }

  load() {

    if (this.data) {
     return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {

      this.http.get('assets/data/locations.json').subscribe(data => {

        this.data = this.applyHaversine(data.locations);

        this.data.sort((locationA, locationB) => {
          return locationA.distance - locationB.distance;
        });

        resolve(this.data);
      });

    });

  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqZ5b.png)

i am pretty new here, and pretty new to ionic, i'll probably requires detailed solution, i cant seems to make ionic read a json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You are getting a compile time error in `data.locations` specifically `locations` is not defined on the data property.

## Fix

Tell TypeScript that it is e.g. use an assertion:

```
  this.data = this.applyHaversine((data as any).locations);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type of your response, you can add a generic to `http.get<T>()` to type `data`.

```
interface SomeInterface {
    locations: Location[]
}

this.http.get('assets/data/locations.json')<SomeInterface>.subscribe(data => {
    this.data = this.applyHaversine(data.locations);
    ...
});
```

or if you don't want to create an interface for it (not recommended)

```
this.http.get('assets/data/locations.json')<SomeInterface>.subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.data = this.applyHaversine(data.locations);
    ...
});
```